# Exported data is null when using it in another javascript vue js file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import

i am developing a shopify theme, currently i am working on shopping cart page, i have CartForm.js file where i am importing data from cartData.js file. This is CartForm.js...

```
import { store } from "./../shared/cartData.js";
if (document.querySelector('.cart-form')) {


    let productForm = new Vue({
        el:".cart-form",
        delimiters: ['${', '}'],
        data(){
            return{
                cart:null,
            }
        },

        created(){ 
            this.getCart();
        },        
        methods:{
            getCart(){
                store.getCart();
                this.cart=store.state.cartData;
                console.log("cart data: "+this.cart);                
        },
```

and this is cartData.js file

```
export const  store = {

    state: {
        cartData:null
    },
    getCart(){   
        alert("store get cart called!...")     

        axios.get('/cart.js')
                .then( response => {                    
                     this.state.cartData=response.data;                     
                    console.log("Responsed data="+this.state.cartData);                    
                })
                .catch( error => {
                    new Noty({
                        type: 'error',
                        layout: 'topRight',
                        text: 'There was an error !!'
                    }).show();
                });
    }

}
```

As you can see i am explicitly calling store.getCart(); in  CartForm's getCart() method, and when "Responsed data" gets printed it shows that this.state.cartData filled with data, but when i am using it like this: this.cart=store.state.cartData; this.cart is null, why is null? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your API takes a while to respond, but JavaScript continues running the function in parallel. Your state is still 'null' while the call hasn't returned, thus this.cart will be set to null, unless you tell JavaScript to wait until the call is finished.

Try making the `getCart()` method an asynchronous function:

```
methods:{
            async getCart(){
                await store.getCart();
                this.cart=store.state.cartData;
                console.log("cart data: "+this.cart);                
        },
```

If cart should always be the same as the data in your store, a better way to do this might be to use a `computed` property for cart. This returns the store.state directly and will help you keep a single source of truth for your data.

```
computed: {
  cart() {
    return store.state.cartData
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you now i have understand what's going on